# Suggestion for a cross platform line graph library for .NET and Mono

Tags: c#, .net, windows, macos, mono

I'm writing a cross platform datalogging application in C# so I use the .NET compiler for Windows and Mono for the Mac. I'm at the stage now where I'm building the GUI for my logging application, I have a plug in arcitecture so am reasonably flexible on what I use.

I'm looking for a charting library to initially plot simple line charts but I may need more complex charts in the future.

I'm currently looking at ZedChart but the development stopped a couple of years ago.

To add to the complications, I'd like a native look and feel so I'm planning to use Windows.Forms on Windows and Cocoa# on the Mac - this may be the stumbling block?

I'm not far enough down the line to stop using Windows.Forms or Cocoa# so I'm open to suggestions on a more elegant solution. I'm suspecting I may need to roll my own, this is not out of the question but I'd rather avoid this if there is something I can use straight away.

Does any one have any suggestions or recomendations?

Comment: Is ZedGraph not actually working?

Comment: It works in .net, I've not tried under mono yet.

Comment: ZedChart? Don't you mean ZedGraph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used ZedGraph in the past in both WinForms applications and from within ASP.Net. It is quite stable, and as mentioned by m_oLogin, is relatively easy to add functionality to.

Alternatively, you could try the [Microsoft Chart Controls](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx). They are based on a version of [Dundas Charts](http://www.dundas.com/), but are free. They can be used in both ASP.Net and WinForms applications. They do require .Net 3.5 however, so may not be entirely suitable for your use.

Answer (score 1):

I'd either go with [NPlot](http://netcontrols.org/nplot/wiki/) or [ZedGraph](http://zedgraph.org/), even though ZG's hasn't evolved recently. The code is cleaner and it's easier to add layers on top of it.